# I am wanting to print the properties of this class, all is well until I see that when I show the AddPet() method in the console

Tags: javascript, class, object, oop

it shows me that I have the value 'perro' that I pass to the object and a value that is undefined when I did not requested it in any other side, what is the cause of this error?

```js
class Usuario {
  constructor(nombre, apellido, libros, mascotas) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.libros = libros;
    this.mascotas = mascotas;
  }

  getFullName() {
    console.log(`${this.nombre} ${this.apellido}`);
  }

  addMascota(mascota) {
    this.mascotas.push(mascota);
  }

  countMascotas() {
    return this.mascotas.length;
  }

  addBook(nombre, autor) {
    this.libros.push(nombre, autor);
  }

  static definicion() {
    console.log("Una persona es un ser humano!");
  }
}

const usuario = new Usuario(
  "John",
  "Doe", [{
    nombre: "El señor de los anillos",
    autor: "J.R.R. Tolkien"
  }], ['perro']
);

usuario.getFullName();
usuario.addMascota();
usuario.countMascotas();

console.log(usuario);
```

Comment: You didn't provide an argument when you called `addMascota()`. What did you expect to be added?

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have added an argument into `addMascota()`
In the initiation you have `this.mascotas` set to `["perro"]`,
so without having an argument for `addMascota()` it will add
undefined to the list, resulting in `["perro", undefined]`
hopefully this helped :)